# Dynamically store objects in an unallocated object in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am stuck in a problem where i have to allocate string objects in an array of strings **But** the problem is i don't know how many string objects i will be putting in this array.

**CODE**

```
   static String[] decipheredMessage;
   static int pointer=0;

   // in another function i have this code
   if(sentenceFormationFlag==true) {
   // System.out.println(" " + word);  // prints the words after sentence formation                 
   // add the words to an array of strings
   decipheredMessage[pointer] = new String();
   decipheredMessage[pointer++] = word;
   return true;
```

What i have done here is i have declared an array of strings and since i don't know how many strings my array is going to contain i dynamically create string objects and assign it to the array.

**ERROR**

$ java SentenceFormation 
arms

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at SentenceFormation.makeSentence(SentenceFormation.java:48)
at SentenceFormation.makeSentence(SentenceFormation.java:44)
at SentenceFormation.makeSentence(SentenceFormation.java:44)
at SentenceFormation.main(SentenceFormation.java:16)
```

I don't know why i am getting this problem can anybody help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic arrays do not work in Java. You need to use one of the fine examples of the collections framework. Import `java.util.ArrayList`.

```
static ArrayList<String> decipheredMessage=new ArrayList<>();;
static int pointer=0;

// in another function i have this code
if(sentenceFormationFlag==true) {
// System.out.println(" " + word);  // prints the words after sentence formation                 
 // add the words to an array of strings
decipheredMessage.add(new String());
decipheredMessage.add(word);
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation like [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you don't know how many elements your array will have.

```
static List<String> decipheredMessage = new ArrayList<>();
...
decipheredMessage.add("my new string");
```

Check out the `List` documentation (linked above) to see what APIs are available.
If you are using Java 5 or 6, you'll need to specify the type in the angled brackets above, i.e. `new ArrayList<String>()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, and read about **List**

```
  List<String>  decipheredMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
   static int pointer=0;

   // in another function i have this code
   if(sentenceFormationFlag==true) {
   // System.out.println(" " + word);  // prints the words after sentence formation                 
   // add the words to an array of strings
   decipheredMessage. add("string1");
   decipheredMessage.add("string2");
   return true;
```